# Why am I getting these Android compatibility warnings in pre-launch report?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

In my app I am targeting Android sdk 29. The prelaunch report is giving a message "We’ve detected that your app is using unsupported APIs" and is giving 22 compatibility warnings. I would like to know which unsupported APIs am I using. Following is one of the stack traces of these warnings.

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J
at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:407)
at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzhz.zzb(zzhz.java:4)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzhz.zzjl(zzhz.java:4)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzhz.<clinit>(zzhz.java:6)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzhz.zza(zzhz.java:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzhz.zza(zzhz.java:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzhz.zza(zzhz.java:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzhz.zza(zzhz.java:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzhz.zzg(zzhz.java:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzhz.zzj(zzhz.java:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzhz.zzji(zzhz.java:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzgp.<clinit>(zzgp.java:5)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzgp.equals(zzgp.java:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzgp.zza(zzgp.java:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzgp.zza(zzgp.java:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzgp.zzd(zzgp.java:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzgc.zzd(zzgc.java:17)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzha.a(zzha.java:19)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzha.a(zzha.java:4)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzfc$zzb.zzhm(zzfc.java:3)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzfc$zzb.zzho(zzfc.java:3)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzfc$zzb.zzhn(zzfc.java:1)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzfc$zzb.zzhp(zzfc.java:1)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzce$zzb.zza(zzce.java:15)
at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzf.zzbt(zzf.java:15)
at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzf.zzc(zzf.java:1)
at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zze.run(zze.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: Any update on this? Facing the same issue after integrating Firebase Performance lib

Comment: Noticed similar issue after integration of Firebase Performance Monitoring:

`StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekLong(JZ)J`

my versions are:
project level: classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'
app-level: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.0.6'

Had to deactivate detectNonSdkApiUsage()